# What user's framebuffer lacks?

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is a comparison of same object using framebuffer texture projected onto screen and "main framebuffer"
[image]

Left image is bit blured while right is more sharp.Alos some options like `glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE )` do not work properly while rendering into the framebuffer.
My "pipeline" looks like this

```
Bind frambuffer
draw all geometry
Unbind
Draw on Quad like as texture.
```

So I wondering why "main frambufffer" can do this while "mine" can't? What are the differences between those two? Does user framebuffers skips some stages? Is it possible to match the quality of main buffer?

```
void Fbo::Build()
{
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

        renderTexId.resize(nColorAttachments);
        glGenTextures(renderTexId.size(),&renderTexId[0]);

        for(int i=0; i<nColorAttachments; i++)
        {
                glBindTexture(format,renderTexId[i]);
                glTexParameterf(format, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameterf(format, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameteri(format, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
                glTexParameteri(format, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
                glTexImage2D(format, 0, type, width, height, 0,  type, GL_FLOAT, 0);
                glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i,renderTexId[i], 0);
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        if(hasDepth)
        {
                glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBufferId);
                glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBufferId);
                glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);

                //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
                glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBufferId);
        }

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
        if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        {
                printf("FBO error, status: 0x%x\n", status);
        }
}
```

Comment: That's funny, the left image looks cleaner to me.  It looks like the left image is doing a bit of anti-aliasing.

Comment: It also looks like the difference between GL_LINEAR (left) and GL_NEAREST (right)

Comment: Looks like antialiasing.

Comment: The left is much smoother as if it is using antialiasing. If it is a texture on a fullscreen quad, wouldn't GL_LINEAR filtering do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "projection" of the FBO onto the screen is subject to sampler state, in particular the texture filter state is to blame here.

By default, if you simply bind the texture attachment you drew into from your FBO to a texture unit and apply it, it is going to use **LINEAR** sampling. This is different from blitting directly to the screen as would traditionally be the case if you were not using an FBO.

**Default State table for Samplers in OpenGL:**
http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf pp. 541, Table 23.18 Textures (state per sampler object)

If you want to replicate the effect of drawing without an FBO, you would want to stretch a quad (or two triangles) over your viewport and use **NEAREST** neighbor sampling for your texture filter. Otherwise, it is going to sample adjacent texels in your FBO and interpolate them for each pixel on screen. This is the cause of your smoother image on the left side, which illustrates a form of anti-aliasing. It is worth mentioning that this is not even close to the same thing as MSAA or SSAA, which increase the sample rate when geometry is rasterized to fix undersampling errors, but it does achieve a similar effect.

Sometimes this is desirable, however. Many processing intensive algorithms run at 1/4, 1/8, or lower resolution and then use a bilinear or bilateral filter to upsample to the viewport resolution without the blockiness associated with nearest neighbor sampling.

The polygon mode state should work just fine. You will need to remember to set it back to GL_FILL before you draw your quad over the viewport though. Again, it all comes back to state management here - your quad will require some very specific states to produce consistent results. To render this way effectively you will probably have to implement a more sophisticated state management system / batch processor, you can no longer simply set `glPolygonMode (...)` once globally and forget it :)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to datenwolf's comments, it should be noted that the above discussion of texture filtering was under the assumption your FBO was at a different resolution than the viewport you were trying to stretch it over.

If your FBO and viewport are at the same resolution, and you are still getting these artifacts from **LINEAR** texture filtering, then you have not setup your texture coordinates correctly. The problem in this scenario is that you are sampling your FBO texture at locations other than the texel centers and this is causing interpolation where none should be necessary.

Fragments are sampled at their centers (non-multisample) in GLSL by default, so if you setup your vertex texture coordinates and positions correctly you will not have to do any texel offset math on your per-vertex texture coordinates. Perspective projection can ruin your day if you are trying to do 1:1 mapping though, so you should either use *orthographic* projection, or better yet use *NDC coordinates* and *no projection at all* when you draw your quad over the viewport.

You can use the following vertex coordinates in *Normalized Device Coordinates*: (-1,-1,-1), (-1,1,-1), (1,1,-1),(1,-1,-1) for the 4 corners of your viewport if you replace the traditional modelview / projection matrices with an identity matrix (or simply do not multiply the vertex position by any matrix in your vertex shader).

You should also use **CLAMP_TO_EDGE** as your wrap state, because this will ensure you never generate texture coordinates outside the range of the center of the first texel and the center of the last texel in a given direction (s,t). **CLAMP** will actually generate values of 0 and 1 (which are not texel centers) for anything at or beyond the edges of the FBO texture attachment.

As a bonus, if you ALWAYS intend to render at 1:1 (FBO vs. viewport), you can avoid using per-vertex texture coordinates altogether and use `gl_FragCoord`. By default in GLSL, `gl_FragCoord` will give you the coordinate for the fragment center (0.5, 0.5), which also happens to be the corresponding texel center in your FBO. You can pass `gl_FragCoord.st` directly to your texture lookup in this special case.

Comment: For any kind of interpolation function, if you evaluate at exactly the sampling points, you must get back exactly the sample values, and nothing interpolated. Or in layman terms: It has *nothing* to do with LINEAR vs. NEAREST. The problem is related to not evaluating the texture at the original sampling points (pixels). That is, because 0 and 1 coordinates are not on pixel centers, but pixel borders.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has _everything_ to do with LINEAR vs. NEAREST. What happens when you sample a texel somewhere other than its center? If you're not using a nearest neighbor filter it will fetch the adjacent texels and interpolate. Granted, the better solution would be to draw the quad with the proper vertex coordinates so that the UV texture coordinates for each fragment align with the texel centers, but this will only happen if the resolution of the FBO matches the viewport. In OpenGL/D3D10+ this is much easier to accomplish than D3D9.

Comment: Using *nearest* filtering is no remedy, because it introduces aliasing between the texture and the screen pixel grid. So depending on the actual resolution some rows/columns may be omitted, while others vanish. No, the only real solution is to sample on the texture pixel centers, by using the right *texture coordinates*, or by using the *texelFetch* shader instruction. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17422950/524368

Comment: We seem to be thinking of the situation in two different ways. My concern is that there is no perfect 1:1 mapping between the number of fragments on screen in his picture and the FBO texture attachment's resolution. The viewport on the left side of the screen isn't even the same aspect ratio. I'm not sure how explicitly fetching texels with `texelFetch (...)` would deliver different behaviour in such a situation? Effectively each fragment's relative area may be larger or smaller than a single texel, so you cannot have each fragment sample the texel center without inherent aliasing.

Comment: Well, say the viewport is 160×120 and the texture is 256×256, then it's perfectly possible to pixel perfect map 160×120 sub portion of the texture to the viewport; (ideally done with texelFetch).