# 2D Ambient lighting in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, lighting

Im making a 2D side scroller game and I am currently implementing lights. The lights are just a light gradient texture rendered on top of the terrain multiplied to make it brighten up the area. However, I dont know how to nor understand how to do Ambient lighting. The following picture sums up what I have and the bottom part is what I want.

[image]

I am open to answers regarding shaders for I know how to use them.

Comment: Ambient lighting is simple, it is the base illumination color in the absence of any light sources. It is uniform across your entire material, and since it has no direction, you can combine it with your accumulated diffuse term in your lighting model. If you are doing multi-pass lighting, you would first do a pass where the terrain is modulated by your constant ambient term and then do additive blending for each additional light's diffuse/specular contribution.

Comment: So when I render the triangles of the raw textures of the terrain I need to pass it through an ambient lighting shader?

Comment: Sort of. Effectively what you want to do is accumulate all of the lighting terms for each light (plus the global ambient term), and then modulate the base texture color by this value at the end. So you would really do additive blending in this order: Ambient, Light0, Light1, Light2, ..., Light N followed by a final pass of multiplicative blending using the base texture color.  It's: (Ambient + Diffuse<For Each Light>) * Base Color

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology. The ambient light is a crude approximation of indirect illumination. Since indirect lights can only increase the brightness you don't want that to achieve the bottom image. To darken an area in the image you can simply reduce the corresponding factors in the light map

Comment: So running one last time, can I make one Framebuffer, render the ambience onto it, render the lights additively onto it, and then draw my terrain triangles while multiplying the terrain texture with the FBO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an FBO texture the size of the screen, clearing it with the color of the ambience and drawing in all nearby lights. Then, I passed it through a shader I made which takes in 2 textures for uniforms. The texture to draw and the light FBO itself. The shader multiplies the textures being drawn with the FBO and it came out nicely.

ambience.frag

```
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main( void ) {
    vec4 color1 = vec4(texture2D(texture1, gl_TexCoord[0].st));
    vec4 color2 = vec4(texture2D(texture2, texCoord));
    gl_FragColor = color1*vec4(color2.r,color2.g,color2.b,1.0);
}
```

ambience.vs

```
varying vec2 texCoord;
uniform vec2 screen;
uniform vec2 camera;

void main(){
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    vec2 temp = vec2(gl_Vertex.x,gl_Vertex.y)-camera;
    texCoord = temp/screen;
}
```

Comment: You should learn to use swizzling in GLSL. Instead of vec4 (color2.r, color2.g, color2.b, 1.0) you can actually do this: vec4 (color2.rgb, 1.0). Likewise in your vertex shader you can use `gl_Vertex.xy` instead of vec2 (gl_Vertex.x, gl_Vertex.y). Also, if texture 2 is a 3 channel texture format, the 4th component is automatically assigned a value of 1.0 by GLSL when you sample it.

Comment: On another related note, if you are going to do lighting this way make sure you use `orthographic` projection when you stretch the FBO texture over the screen. You need your pixel centers to align with texel centers, or you will wind up with texture filtering issues blurring (linear) or aliasing (nearest). Perspective correction will often mis-align your texture coordinates. I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152963/what-users-framebuffer-lacks/18153766#18153766 recently.