# Texture repeating on quads OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, repeat

I am writing a voxel engine and at the moment
I am working on the Chunk-Rendering-System but I have a problem.
It seems that the textures were repeated on the quads.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iuuN.png]

There is this green line at the bottom of the grass blocks and I don't know why.

This is the OpenGL-Render-Code:

```
Texture texture = TextureManager.getTexture(block.getTextureNameForSide(Direction.UP));
texture.bind();
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(0, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(1, 0); GL11.glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(1, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
GL11.glTexCoord2d(0, 1); GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
GL11.glEnd();
```

And here is the OpenGL-Setup:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
GL11.glClearColor(0.1F, 0.4F, 0.6F, 0F);
GL11.glClearDepth(1F);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` are set to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.

Comment: @user3512521: You should accept this answer rather than commenting with "thank you." Right now the question appears unanswered because there is no accepted answer.

Comment: I am new here, sorry. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*genpfault's answer should do the trick for you, I just wanted to give you some insight into **why** you need this particular wrap state.*</sup>

To be clear, the green line in your screenshot corresponds to the edges of one of your voxels?

It looks like you are using `GL_LINEAR` filtering (default) together with an inappropriate texture wrap state (e.g. `GL_REPEAT` or `GL_CLAMP`). I will explain why `GL_CLAMP` is a bad idea later.

---

You may think that the texture coordinate **0.0** and **1.0** are perfectly within the normalized texture coordinate range and therefore not subject to wrapping, but you would be wrong.

This particular combination of states will pickup texels from the other side of your texture at either extreme of the [0,1] texture coordinate range. The texture coordinate **1.0** is actually slightly *beyond* the ***center*** of the last texel in your texture, so when GL fetches the 4 ***nearest*** texels for linear filtering, it wraps around to the other side of the texture for at least 2 of them.

`GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` modifies this behavior, it clamps the texture coordinates to a range that is actually more restrictive than [0,1] so that no coordinate goes beyond the *center* of any edge texels in your texture. Linear filtering will not pickup texels from the other side of your texture with this set. You could also (mostly) fix this by using `GL_NEAREST` filtering, but that will result in a lot of texture aliasing.

---

It is also possible that you are using `GL_CLAMP`, which, by the way was removed in OpenGL 3.1. In older versions of GL it was designed to clamp the coordinates into the range [0,1] and then if linear filtering tried to fetch a texel beyond the edge it would use a special set of border texels rather than wrapping around. Border texels are no longer supported, and thus that wrap mode is gone.

The bottom line is do not use `GL_CLAMP`, it does not do what most people think. `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is almost always what you *really* want when you think of clamping textures.

---

#### EDIT:

genpfault brings up a good point; this would be a lot easier to understand with a diagram...

#### The following diagram illustrates the problem in 1 dimension:

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC83860.gif

I have a more thorough explanation of this diagram in an answer I wrote to a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323188/texture-coordinates-near-1-behave-oddly/19323954#19323954).

Comment: [<insert datenwolf's standard texcoord fencepost diagram here>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17422950/44729)